# How to exit from ssh session and execute commands on the last shell from a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ssh, logout

I'm trying to write a small shell script. It should exit from the current ssh session but after that execute commands on my local computer. I don't know if thats even possible. The situation is the following: I modify a project, test and build it on my buildserver. When I start the script I would be on my buildserver and I would have modified and tested the project. Now I want a script to speed of the process of compiling the project and installing it on my local computer. To do this manually I would basically do something like the following:

```
user@buildserver:~$ ./build project
user@buildserver:~$ exit
user@localcomputer:~$ scp buildserver:/home/user/project/binary /tmp
user@localcomputer:~$ /home/user/install /tmp/binary
```

The only thing I got working so far is to exit from the ssh session by calling `logout` in s shell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A script running on a remote computer you’re connected to through SSH cannot execute commands on your computer without making a further SSH connection to your computer (which may not be an option if you’re behind a NAT or do not have an SSH server running).

A possible alternative may be to have a script on your computer that runs the shell script on the remote computer through SSH; once that remote script has finished, the local SSH client will exit and your local script can continue exiting whatever local commands are desired.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll install a ssh client on my local computer.

Comment: @timgame: You probably already have an SSH client. Otherwise, I’m not sure how you’re connecting to `buildserver` in the first place!

Comment: No, you don't need a server.  The script you run locally would be basically `ssh buildserver 'cd place; build project' && scp buildserver:place/binary /tmp && install /tmp/binary` (assuming `build project` will properly exit with a nonzero exit code if something fails).